# Fullcalendar save record in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a drag & drop calendar(Fullcalendar) and saving  the new or edited items in a MySQL database.

But I'm having 2 problems at the moment.

### First:

I can't drag & drop more then 1 item in the month view:
http://snag.gy/SF9wI.jpg

But if I drag a new one in the Week view ,It works : http://snag.gy/0tW2m.jpg
and if I go back to the Month view the ones I just created in the Week view are still there.

### Second:

I'm new in ajax,jquery and I don't really know how to use $_post, so I can save my records in my MySQL database. I tried a few guides but no success.

MySQL database:

name: ***tblEvent***

```
idEvent INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY
fiTask INT
fiUser INT
dtStart DATETIME
dtEnd DATETIME
dtUrl VARCHAR(255)
dtAllDay TINYINT(1)
```

index.php:

```
<?php
include_once './Includes/functions.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <link href='../fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <link href='../fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
        <script src='../lib/moment.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
        <script src='../fullcalendar.js'></script>
        <script src='../lang/de.js'></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var date = new Date();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();
                var h = {};


                /* initialize the external events
                 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

                $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function () {

                    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });

                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });

                });


                /* initialize the calendar
                 -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                    },
                    slotEventOverlap: false,
                    eventLimit: true,
                    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                    events: "./event.php",
                    // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
                    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                            event.allDay = true;
                        } else {
                            event.allDay = false;
                        }
                    },
                    selectable: true,
                    selectHelper: true,
                    select: function (start, end, allDay) {
                        var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                        var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exits:');
                        var eventData;
                        if (title) {
                            var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            $.ajax({
                                url: './add_event.php',
                                data: 'title=' + title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&url=' + url,
                                type: "POST",
                                success: function (json) {
                                    alert('Added Successfully');
                                }
                            });

                            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                                    {
                                        title: title,
                                        start: start,
                                        end: end,
                                        allDay: allDay
                                    },
                            true // make the event "stick"
                                    );
                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
                    },
                    editable: true,
                    /*eventDrop: function (event, delta) {
                        var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        $.ajax({
                            url: './update_events.php',
                            data: 'title=' + event.title + '&start=' + start + '&end=' + end + '&id=' + event.id,
                            type: "POST",
                            success: function (json) {
                                alert("Updated Successfully");
                            }
                        });
                    }*/


                });
            });

        </script>
        <style>

            body {
                margin-top: 40px;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 14px;
                font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
            }

            #wrap {
                width: 1100px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

            #external-events {
                float: left;
                width: 150px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                border: 1px solid #ccc;
                background: #eee;
                text-align: left;
            }

            #external-events h4 {
                font-size: 16px;
                margin-top: 0;
                padding-top: 1em;
            }

            #external-events .fc-event {
                margin: 10px 0;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            #external-events p {
                margin: 1.5em 0;
                font-size: 11px;
                color: #666;
            }

            #external-events p input {
                margin: 0;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            #calendar {
                float: right;
                width: 900px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='wrap'>

            <div id='external-events'>
                <h3>Aufgaben</h3>
                <?php
                foreach (SelectTask() as $x) {
                    echo "<div class='fc-event'>" . $x['dtTask'] . "</div>";
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <div id='calendar'></div>

            <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

event.php:

```
    <?php

// List of events
$json = array();

// Query that retrieves events
$requete = "SELECT * FROM tblEvent";

// connection to the database
try {
    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=10.140.2.19;dbname=dbcontrol', 'ymartins', 'a15370430x');
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$resultat = $dbc->query($requete) or die(print_r($dbc->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
echo json_encode($resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

add_event.php:

```
    <?php

// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
// connection to the database
try {
    $dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=10.140.2.19;dbname=dbcontrol', '****', ****);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblEvent (dtTitle, dtStart, dtEnd, dtUrl) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :url)";
$q = $dbc->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title' => $title, ':start' => $start, ':end' => $end, ':url' => $url));
?>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I improve my script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to expand your question to include exactly what is going wrong/not working?

I see one issue at least:

your AJAX call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/add_event.php',
    data: {'title': title, 'start': start ...}
    type: "POST",
    success: function (json) {
        alert('Added Successfully');
    }
});
```

complete the 'data:' line... its a dict, not a GET Url encoded string when using POST.
you may also want to add a failure section to catch errors, or at least print out the value of the 'json' in case your php page throws an error (it will be in that variable of the success callback).